# Haskell: call function inside another on every tuple in a list

Tags: dictionary, haskell

I have a general list of tuple like so Map.fromList [(10,20),(30,40),(50,60)]

```
-- takes list of tuples and produce another list of tuples  
GeneralFunction ::Ord m -> [(m,m)] -> Map m [m] -> Map m [m]

-- takes a tuple (x,y) and produce [(x,y),(y,x)] for each tuple in the general list 
specialFunction ::Ord m -> (m,m) -> Map m [m]
```

I have generalFunction in which I want to call a special function which takes a tuple (x,y) and insert in (x,y) (y,x) for each tuple of the general list **depending on its length**

Eg : when I call `GeneralFunction` with `Map.fromList [(10,20),(30,40),(50,60)]`
the final result will be like so `Map.fromList [(10,20),(20,10),(30,40),(40,30),(50,60),(60,50)]`

I know how to use insertWith key value and how to use list.

**Question:**

I'm more stack with the process of iterating tuple by tuple

Any indications, ideas or hints are welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is leaving aside `Map` in `specialFunction` and think if they were just lists of tuples:

```
specialFunction :: Ord m -> (m, m) -> [(m, m)]
specialFunction (a, b) = [(a, b), (b, a)]
```

And then, I'm not quite sure what your `generalFunction` does, but you can use `specialFunction` likewise:

```
generalFunction :: Ord m -> [(m, m)] -> Map m m
generalFunction = Map.fromList . concat . map specialFunction
```

If you want to apply some function over a list of values, you can always use `map` (also, you have a `map` for the `Map` datatype).

Hence, you get:

```
Prelude Data.Map> generalFunction [(10,20),(30,40),(50,60)]
fromList [(10,20),(20,10),(30,40),(40,30),(50,60),(60,50)]
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, I appreciate your help.